# ファインチューニングの精度向上について

Tags: 深層学習, keras

ファインチューニングを行なっているのですが、今までvgg16の全結合層のみをいじりながら畳み込み層はフリーズさせていました。しかし、一度この畳み込み層もフリーズせずに学習可能にしたところもともと80パーセントほどだった精度が一気に90パーセントぐらいまで跳ね上がりました。これは正常な学習ができている状態なのでしょうか？どうにも不安です。
転移学習において畳み込み層を学習可能にする事で精度が跳ね上がるなんてことはありえるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

学習データ不足の場合に過学習を防ぐために畳み込み層を固定にすることが多いだけで、学習用のデータが十分多ければ学習可能な層が多いほど精度が上がるのは当然です。
訓練時の精度もバリデーション時の精度も上がっているのでしたら問題ないと思います。